# ¿cómo puedo insertar el resto de imágenes en un subplot?

Tags: python-3.7

tengo un DataFrame así

```
df=pd.DataFrame(dat)
```

visualizando los datos:

```
            AP2  Paron  AP1 Artesoncocha Llanganuco
fecha
2018-09-01  0.1   0.0   0.0     0.0        0.0
2018-09-02  0.1   0.0   0.0     0.0        0.0
2018-09-03  1.0   0.2   0.0     0.4        2.0
```

Agrupo estos datos diarios en meses así:

```
dat_mes = dat.groupby(lamnda m:m.month)
mes = dat.resample('M').sum()
print(mes)
```

out

```
              AP2    Paron   AP1  Artesoncocha Llanganuco
fecha
2018-09-30    22.8   35.6   37.0    49.8         35.8
2018-10-31   123.5  100.8   99.8   125.6        133.0
2018-11-30   151.0  108.2  100.6   123.4        132.6
```

un primer gráfico lo realizo así:

```
mes.plot(kind='bar')
```

quiero hacer el mismo gráfico para cada uno que se muestra en la leyenda, y hago lo siguiente, aunque no es nada elegante:

```
columns = ['AP2','Paron','AP1','Artesoncocha','Llanganuco']
ax=plt.subplots(2,3)

for col in columns:
    for j in range(0,6):
        graf =mes[col].plot(subplots=True, kind='bar')
```

el resultado no es lo que espero, la gráfica sale así XD... y cómo podría sólo mostrarla fecha sin los ceros?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si añade `plt.subplot(2, 3, j+1)` en la linea despues de `for j in range(0,6):`, ¿funciona?

Y tambien, si usa `subplot=True`, no necisita `for`-loop por cada column. Por ejemplo:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame as df
a = np.random.random((3,4))
b = df(a)
b.plot(subplots=True, kind='bar')
```

Puede encontrar la documentación aqui (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

Comment: Gracias!!!, realicé lo sugerido y se grafican todos los subplots pero con la misma columna ... XD, en este caso Llanganuco en todos los gráficos. Y con la segunda opción salen los gráficos, con el número de columnas igual al número de filas y en una sola columna, que está bien se entiende chevere. y gracias por el link de la documentación y sabes como tener sólo las fechas en el eje X?

Comment: Creo que puede encontrar una menera que funcione en estes respuestas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133280/pandas-bar-plot-changes-date-format  Parece que no es tan facil como espero...

Comment: muchas gracias Health!!!!!, a revisar entonces.....

Comment: Hola antonio, si cree que mi respuesta le ayuda, por favor puede marcarlo como aceptada?

Comment: .... ok chevere.... y cómo hago eso?

Comment: ¡Gracias! Para aceptarlo puede clic en la marca de verificacion a lado la respuesta.